# Decode powershell command to code

Tags: powershell

It is possible decode (or show what to do) command Powershell?

I try use command `connect-msolservice`, but i get exceptions:

[image].

So maybe if I get content command, i can configure system to this connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use ILSpy to decode powershell dll. [Download ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). 
For find path .dll with your cmdlets, use powershell command:

`Get-Command connect-msolservice | fl DLL,ImplementingType`

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use a native solution to view the Metadata of the builtin (or any other cmdlets)

```
$Metadata = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData (Get-Command Connect-MSOLService)
$Contents = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($Metadata)
```

credit to http://windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-proxy-functions

Comment: Looks useful for getting information in the interface (I use the word hesitatingly) to a cmdlet, but I guess that creating a ProxyCommand based on the command metadata is more like reverse-engineering the cmdlet than actually revealing what it does?

Comment: It allows you to add functionality as the proxy function wraps the original command let. I use it to proxy all the `write-host`, `write-warning`, `write-error` etc. cmdlets to add a `-log $logfile` parameter this makes logging boilerplate less intrusive in the code